# How to set footnotes per chapter?

Tags: numbering, bigfoot

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany,openbib]{book} 
\usepackage[total={5in, 8in}]{geometry} 
\usepackage[ruled]{bigfoot}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}  
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[arabic]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{C}[roman]
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{5mm}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{chapter 1}
     Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing chapter 1\footnoteA{Chapter 1 footnote a Chapter 1 footnote B\footnoteB{Chapter 1 footnote b Chapter 1 footnote C\footnoteC{Chapter 1 footnote c Chapter 1 footnote c Chapter 1 footnote c Chapter 1 footnote c } Chapter 1 footnote b Chapter 1 footnote b Chapter 1 footnote b } Chapter 1 footnote a Chapter 1 footnote a }
    Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing 

    \chapter{chapter 2}
    Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing\footnoteA{chapter 2 footnote a, chapter 2 footnote B,\footnoteB{chapter 2 footnote b, chapter 2 footnote b,\footnoteC{chapter 2 footnote c, chapter 2 footnote c, chapter 2 footnote c, chapter 2 footnote c, } chapter 2 footnote b, chapter 2 footnote b, chapter 2 footnote b, chapter 2 footnote b, } chapter 2 footnote a, chapter 2 footnote a, chapter 2 footnote a, } Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing 


\end{document}
```

The footnotes are set to appear per page, but I need them appearing per chapter, namely that all footnotes of a chapter appear at the end of every chapter. I need footnotes appearing in the form of {chapter number, page number, footnote mark}

Comment: Can you please add a MWE that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: After looking at your previous questions, before adding the MWE, please take a moment and read [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly what you ask for but very close. You can add some `\newpage` in appropriate places to check the page numbering in the footnotes. Since you want the footnotes at the end of each chapter I just used numbers as footnote marks and for each chapter this numbering is reset.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany,openbib]{book} 
\usepackage[total={5in, 8in}]{geometry} 

\usepackage{endnotes,chngcntr}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\makeatletter         %<-- these lines add the page numbering
\long\def\@endnotetext#1{%
    \if@enotesopen \else \@openenotes \fi
    \immediate\write\@enotes{\@doanenote{\@theenmark \ [pg \thepage]}}
    \begingroup
    \def\next{#1}
    \newlinechar='40
    \immediate\write\@enotes{\meaning\next}%
    \endgroup
    \immediate\write\@enotes{\@endanenote}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\notesname}{Footnotes of Chapter \thechapter} %<-- this is for the title of the footnotes at the end of the chapter
\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter} %<-- this restarts the numbering of the footnotes for each chapter, requires the package "chngcntr"
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{chapter 1}
     Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing\footnote{a footnote} Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing\footnote{another footnote} Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing\footnote{A third footnote}
    Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing\footnote{one footnote more} Testing Testing 

\begingroup
\parindent 0pt
\parskip 2ex
\def\enotesize{\normalsize}
\theendnotes %<---- this prints all the footnotes together
\endgroup

    \chapter{chapter 2}
     Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing\footnote{a footnote} Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing\footnote{another footnote} Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing\footnote{A third footnote}
Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing\footnote{one footnote more} Testing Testing 

\begingroup
\parindent 0pt
\parskip 2ex
\def\enotesize{\normalsize}
\theendnotes
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is helpful. Would you please let one more type of footnote (not only one type) = endnote?

Comment: The page numbers of footnotes are incorrect.